# DataGridView doesn't display an auto-counting variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a form which contains a button and a DataGridView.

The button allows me to add a new person to the database :

```
DataRow drow = sql.ds.Tables["Etablissement"].NewRow();
            drow[1] = nom.Text; //drow[0] it's an auto-countign var
            drow[2] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ville.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)ville.Text;
            sql.ds.Tables["Etablissement"].Rows.Add(drow);
            SqlCommandBuilder cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(daEtablissement);
            daEtablissement.Update(sql.ds, "Etablissement");
            dgv.Refresh(); // dgv : DataGridView that i'm usign
            XtraMessageBox.Show("Bien Ajouter !");
            Videz();
            nom.Focus();
```

the problem is when the DataGridView is refreshed the code of the person I added doesn't display, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) method is just a UI refresh and not data binding refresh. The best and simple way is to use a `BindingSource` which has your `DataTable` as a data source, and the `BindingSource` is set as the data source of the grid. Usually when you update the `DataTable`, the grid should show the new data, but if it doesn't happen you can call `BindingSource.ResetBindings(false)`

Code:

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable;
myGrid.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

If for any reason updating the data table does not refresh the grid you can call:

```
bindingSource.ResetBindings(false); // put true if your metadata has also changed
```

Comment: I used this code in the Form_Load Event :

BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = sql.ds.Tables["Etablissement"] };
            dgv.DataSource = bindingSource;
            bindingSource.ResetBindings(false);

But the code still not displaying !!

Comment: Use `ResetBindings` only after you add a new row.